# Javascript and HTML Homework tracker. Delete function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a homework tracker. I am currently able to add and delete homework items which are inputted by the user. However, there is a problem where if you delete an item by clicking the delete button, you can click anywhere on any other homework item and it will delete it even though you did not press the delete button.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Homework</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Homework Tracker</h1> 

    <br>

    <div class="AddNewSub">

        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px;  vertical-align: middle;">receipt</i>

            <textarea id="addhw" placeholder="Input Homework"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="addbutton" onclick="add()"> Add </button>

    </div>
    <br>

        <div id="MainContents">

        </div>


    <script>

        var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
        document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserInputCon')); 


        function add() {

            var contents = document.getElementById('addhw').value;

            contents = contents.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');

            var newline = document.createElement('div');
            newline.setAttribute("class", "close");
            newline.setAttribute("id", "UserConDiv")

            newline.innerHTML = "<div id='contentdiv'>" + contents + "</div>" + " " + "<button type='button' id='delbutton' onclick='deletehw()'>Delete</button>" + "<br>";


            document.getElementById("MainContents").appendChild(newline);
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));


        }

        function deletehw() {

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
              close[i].onclick = function() {
                var div = this.parentElement;
                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
                localStorage.removeItem('UserInputCon');
                localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));

              } 

            }
        }




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that code. Look at `deletehw`... what does it do? It binds click handlers. Is that what you wanted to do? I don't think so. That code should delete the element from the list, but it is not doing that. It just assigns functions the `onclick` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your delete function. At the moment you are iteration over the "close" items, but close is not the button but the whole homework entry, so on click on any of this, you will delete them.

Try this code:
But i would suggest you to use event binding and not directly print onclick in the element. Also you should use a template for your homework entry

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Homework</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Homework Tracker</h1> 

    <br>

    <div class="AddNewSub">

        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px;  vertical-align: middle;">receipt</i>

            <textarea id="addhw" placeholder="Input Homework"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="addbutton" onclick="add()"> Add </button>

    </div>
    <br>

        <div id="MainContents">

        </div>


    <script>

        var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
        document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserInputCon')); 


        function add() {

            var contents = document.getElementById('addhw').value;

            contents = contents.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');

            var newline = document.createElement('div');
            newline.setAttribute("class", "close");
            newline.setAttribute("id", "UserConDiv")

            newline.innerHTML = "<div id='contentdiv'>" + contents + "</div>" + " " + "<button type='button' id='delbutton' onclick='deletehw(this)'>Delete</button>" + "<br>";


            document.getElementById("MainContents").appendChild(newline);
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));


        }

        function deletehw(element) {

            let container = element.parentElement;
            container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
            localStorage.removeItem('UserInputCon');
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));
        }




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The line that sets an `id` attribute to `UserConDiv`, and the HTML attribute that sets the nested div element's `id` to `contentdiv` can be removed because it's not valid to have duplicate id values in the DOM - they don't appear to be needed in any case.

Comment: i agree, i just copied the code from TO. There are a lot of other mistakes there, i just fixed the one, that was asked for